# semantic-ui-react Basic Modal throwing Invariant Violation: Portal.render()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, modal-dialog, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to incorporate a basic modal ([documented here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#types-basic)) into an existing React component. 
Without a modal, the button renders fine.

```
class NewInstanceModal extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    render() {
        console.log('modal render');
        return (<Button>Basic Modal</Button>);
    }
}
```

When I add in the modal component as shown in the semantic-ui-react docs, it compiles fine (typescript), but throws an error at runtime.

Code:

```
class NewInstanceModal extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    render() {
        console.log('modal render');
        return (
            <Modal trigger={<Button>Basic Modal</Button>} basic size='small'>
                <Header icon='archive' content='Archive Old Messages' />
                <Modal.Content>
                    <p>Your inbox is getting full, would you like us to enable automatic archiving of old messages?</p>
                </Modal.Content>
                <Modal.Actions>
                    <Button basic color='red' inverted>
                        <Icon name='remove' />No
                    </Button>
                    <Button color='green' inverted>
                        <Icon name='checkmark' />Yes
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Actions>
            </Modal>
            );
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Invariant Violation: Portal.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

This component is rendered within another component. I am using typescript version 2.5, semantic-ui-react 0.82.0, semantic-ui-css 2.3.3.

Comment: Is there a reason `Header` is not taken from `Modal`? Did you separately import it?

Comment: I copied that code snippet for the modal directly from semantic-ui-react documentation. Yes, I separately import Header as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error by updating React to the latest version, 16.4.2